# Obtain function constant index for MTLArgument

Tags: metal

`MTLRenderPipelineReflection` contain lists of `MTLArgument`'s that contains info about name, index, type, access, e.t.c. except any info about function constant binding.
There are `MTLFunction` and it's dictionary `var functionConstantsDictionary: [String : MTLFunctionConstant]`, that keyed by function constant name(it feels excess because MTLFunctionConstant already contains name). I did not found any info about function constants that in use of argument.
As a result should be something like table [FunctionArgumentName: FunctionConstant]
Is there any info about pipeline that helps to calculate that bindings?

**UPD:**

```metal
fragment float4 fragment_main(VertexOut in [[stage_in]],
                                  texture2d<float> baseColorTexture [[texture(BaseColorTexture), function_constant(hasColorTexture)]],
                                  texture2d<float> normalTexture [[texture(NormalTexture), function_constant(hasNormalTexture)]],
                                  texture2d<float> aoTexture [[texture(AOTexture), function_constant(hasAOTexture)]],
                                  texturecube<float> reflectionTextureCube [[texture(ReflectionTextureCube), function_constant(hasReflectionTextureCube)]]) {
    /// Shader code
}
```

In other words I need to access name of function constant for `baseColorTexture` argument of this shader function from swift code

Comment: It's not super-clear what you are asking here.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to extract this information